# What's the composition of primes in Goldbach's Conjecture?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

**Lemma**

For $n>5$, every even number $2n$ can be expressed as a sum of four primes $p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3$.

**Proof**

Let $p_0$ be an odd prime and $m = 2n - p_0$ an odd number.

Applying the Weak Goldbach Conjecture (H. Helfgott), $m = p_1 + p_2 + p_3$.

Rearranging, $2n = p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3 \blacksquare$

---

**Question**

From the lemma, $2n = p_0 + (p_1 + p_2 + p_3)$ and Goldbach's conjecture states $2n = q_0+q_1$.

Equating the two expressions $q_0+q_1 = p_0 + p_1 + p_2 + p_3$

Doesn't this impose constraints on the form of the $q_0, q_1$ primes?

**Example**

If $q_0=p_0$ then $q_1=p_1+p_2+p_3$ is constrained to the sum of $3$ primes.

For example, let $n=6$, by the lemma, $12=5+(3+2+2)$ and by Goldbach, $12=5+7$.

Equating yields $5+7=5+(3+2+2)$ where $q_0=p_0=5$ and $q_1=p_1+p_2+p_3=3+2+2=7$.

Comment: This is quite vague.  In a similar way,  Goldbach applied to $2n$ and $2n+2$ tells us that $p_0+p_1+2=p_2+p_3$ for suitable primes.  But so what?

Comment: @lulu As you noted, it probably has no significance. But it was fun thinking about it and trying to follow mathematical steps which I hope at least are correct? :)

Comment: You might be interested in this : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283906626_A_Twin_Prime_Analog_of_Goldbach%27s_Conjecture

Comment: ...Any multiple of 12 greater than 24 can be written as the sum of two twin pairs, making it the twin prime equivalent of the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: @mick I never heard of an equivalence of Goldbach and the twin prime conjecture. Can you work out this equivalence ?

Comment: @Peter not equivalent as in the same. More like analogue.